# Update Opportunity Page Layouts per each Opportunity Stage

Tags: workflow, opportunity, page-layout, record-type, savepoint

I have two Opportunity Stages. Stage A and Stage B. When I move from Stage A to Stage B, I want certain fields on the page to appear and certain fields to be made required (that were not originally required at Stage A).

I have used Record Types /Workflow to cater for this but when I change the Stage B, which updates the Record Type (on save) which in turn, let's me save the record without having to populate the new fields /new required fields. When I edit the page (second time around), THEN I have to fill out the required fields.

Can anyone advise on a method of making the fields (on Stage B) required as specified above the first time that I try and save the record without using Apex?

Answer (score 1):

Create a validation rule for the additional fields that become required when the Stage changes which includes a test `if( Stage = B)` or (!= B), depending on how you set up the validation rules. When you try to save a record and the Stage = B, those rules should be activated. When you write your rules, you'll need to consider how to handle any Stages that might occur beyond Stage B.